# MVC3 + EF4 + MySQL System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm developing a ASP.NET MVC3 web application, which uses Entity Framework 4.1 and MySQL.

Locally all works well, but when I deploy the solution to the web host, it gives me the following error message:

> System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed. at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(RuntimeAssembly
>   asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand,
>   IPermission permThatFailed) at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Object
>   assemblyOrString, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand,
>   IPermission permThatFailed) at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(PermissionSet
>   grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, Object assemblyOrString,
>   SecurityAction action, Boolean throwException) at
>   System.Security.PermissionSetTriple.CheckSetDemand(PermissionSet
>   demandSet, PermissionSet& alteredDemandset,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh) at
>   System.Security.PermissionListSet.CheckSetDemand(PermissionSet pset,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh) at
>   System.Security.PermissionListSet.DemandFlagsOrGrantSet(Int32 flags,
>   PermissionSet grantSet) at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ReflectionTargetDemandHelper(Int32
>   permission, PermissionSet targetGrant, CompressedStack
>   securityContext) at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ReflectionTargetDemandHelper(Int32
>   permission, PermissionSet targetGrant) The action that failed was:
>   Demand The type of the first permission that failed was:
>   System.Security.PermissionSet

My Web.Config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySqlMembershipConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;userid=userName;password=passw0rd;database=tv;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient,Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
    <add name="TvEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.Model.csdl|res://*/Entities.Model.ssdl|res://*/Entities.Model.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=127.0.0.1;port=3351;User Id=userName;password=passw0rd;Persist Security Info=True;database=tv&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <clear />
        <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
        type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data,Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Trustlevel is on Medium.

Any ideas?

Comment: And you have remembered to change your web.config so it's not pointing at localhost? If I had a penny for every time I'd forgotten, I'd have about 4 pennies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always switch to another hosting provider with full trust?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use newer version of the connector. It was [reported as a bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=59202) and should be fixed in 6.3.7 and 6.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Add the reference to System.Web.Providers. If the assembly is not available locally install it using NuGet Package Manager as follows:

```
PM> Install-Package System.Web.Providers
```

Also verify in the web.config file that the following entry has been added to the profile section

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider,            
                   System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  
                   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"   
                   connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Then you can rebuild the application and execute it.